# Chrome devtools extension - On devtools close event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing Chrome devtools plugin.

**devtools.js**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("Override Debug",
  null,
  "panel.html",
  (panel) => {
    panel.onShown.addListener(addDebugger);
    panel.onHidden.addListener(destroyDebugger);
  }
);
```

So when user navigates to `Override Debug` tab in devtools, I'm initializing debugger. 
When user navigating away from my devtool, I'm discarding debugger - **Which is working great**

Now the issue comes, when user navigates to `Override Debug` and closed devtools completely, debugger still alive making page un responsive.

I tried to see events in `panel` object `chrome.devtools` objects also tried entire github to see if we have such event. No luck.

Is there any event that monitors devtools close event to discard the debugger I attached?

**Update 1**

Tried to attach `Inspector.enable` command as follows but no luck. It never got `Inspector.detached` message

```
function addDebugger() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(target) {
    debuggee = { tabId: target.id };

    chrome.debugger.attach(debuggee, "1.2", () => {
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggee, "Network.setRequestInterception", { patterns: [{ urlPattern: '*' }] });
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggee, "Inspector.enable");
    });



    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener((source, method, params) => {
      if (source.tabId === target.id) {
        if (method === "Network.requestIntercepted") {
          // Do many things
        } else if (method === "Inspector.detached") {
          destroyDebugger();
        }
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Simple method in [this answer](/a/48287643) (you need to insert that code using chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval). Another solution might be to use `chrome.debugger` API and send `Inspector.enable` command then watch for `Inspector.detached` event, [more info](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Inspector).

Comment: @wOxxOm Where on the earth this link is hidden!!!! Thanks for sharing, but unfortunately it's not working for me. Updated my question with what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the issue comes, when user navigates to Override Debug and closed devtools

Add a listener on `beforeunload` event inside `panel.html` of `Override Debug` dev-tools panel, so that when dev-tools is closed by [x] or F12 buttons etc. - the `page.html` (that is just an `iframe` inside dev-tools application) will receive it.

Be aware of possibly undesired side effect of this solution that wouldn't be expected from `panel.onHidden` behaviour (if only it worked as expected) - that may arise during the development - the event will also fire on [context menu->Reload Frame] command.

```js
// page.html
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  // destroyDebugger() or post a message to destroy it from devtools.js
});
```